# Acess each information in Firebase database using Thunkable

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, thunkable

How do I access every ‘route’ value under d? Every userid can either be c or d, and I want to access and add all numbers under ‘route' if they belong to d. I don't know how to access other information because I don't have other's UID when logged on to a specific account.

[image]